# foreach function only show last value

Tags: php

when i wanna get all value to check with current user ip it just check last ip with current user , i don't know why before values doesnt check.

i fill IPs in a textarea like this : 176.227.213.74,176.227.213.78

```
                elseif($maintenance_for == '2') {
                $get_ips = $options['ips'];
                $explode_ips = explode(',',$get_ips);
                foreach ($explode_ips as $ips) {
                    if($ips == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]){
                        $maintenance_mode = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        $maintenance_mode = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you found the right value, you wan't to `BREAK` out of the `foreach loop`

```
$get_ips = $options['ips'];
$explode_ips = explode(',', $get_ips);
foreach($explode_ips as $ips) {
    if ($ips == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) {
        $maintenance_mode = true;
        break; // If the IP is right, BREAK out of the foreach, leaving $maintenance_mode to true
    } else {
        $maintenance_mode = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jessieomline, glad it worked. What i recommend is that you combine my answer with the answer of `Darkmukke`. So set the `$maintenance_mode` default to `false` and get rid of the `else` statement.

Comment: @Mathlight yes that works, break is the optimizer here, saves you having to go trough an array of for example 100 ips is the server ip is the 2nd one, in my answer i set a default flag because with php you never know what might go wrong

Comment: @jessieomline changed my answer aswell to give you another option if you just need a boolean

Answer (score 3):

yes, you will always override it. Its better to set a default and only set it once:
(Edit: added @Mathlight's answer, the break, in my solution as he suggested)

```
$maintenance_mode = false;
foreach ($explode_ips as $ips) {
    if($ips == $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]){
        $maintenance_mode = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT : another solution for the record, for the points of a oneliner**

```
$maintenance_mode = in_array($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $explode_ips);
```